# Плохо отображается NavigationView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer

Я хотел делать так, что бы NavigationView не накладывался на Tollbar при развертывани. Узнал как это сделать. Сделал. Но получилось у меня все совсем не так, в чем же проблема?

код activity_main :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

код app_bar_main:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попроббуйте android:fitsSystemWindows="true" убрать у NavigationView

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: А зачем у вас 2 AppBarLayout? Попробуйте убрать один из них

Comment: Бесполезно. Ничего не меняется

Comment: Исправьте вопрос - кажется у вас там в разметке все элементы по два раза. Расскажите какая разметка в какой расположена.